# How to scale/repeat texture on object? (blender internal)

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

How do I make the texture on my object smaller? (I'm pretty new to blender, any help would be appreciated)
[image: object and texture panel]

I want that texture repeated, (e.g to make the whole thing look like lizard skin)

Comment: Can you show your UV setup or post the .blend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the properties panel, textures tab, go to the mapping section and modify the size of the texture.

For fast editing of the 3 values simultaneously, left click on the x fileld, drag to z field without releasing, then - still without releasing - drag left to decrease and right to increase the value.

A bigger value means smaller texture.

Comment: Did not work, edited the size either way (.1 & 20 sizes) and the texture still looks the same

Comment: Switch from " textured" to "material" or "rendered" view. In Blender internal textured view lets you see the texture you choosed at the moment of the unwrap, so you can change its scale only scaling the whole  UV (which is another method you can use to set the scaling of a texture).

Comment: BTW, did you set up a material already?